# What are all the animations can we do in JointJS?

Tags: jointjs

I what to know what kind of animations that JointJS provides?

is there any documentation or link that I can refer?

Answer (score 1):

You can read about transition available in JointJS  [here](http://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:transition)